# JobHost.RunAndBlock not blocking

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I have implemented a long running process as a WebJob which is triggered upon a queue message. My understanding is that `JobHost.RunAndBlock()` would only start executing once the current job has completed and returned. However, if my first process is still running when another queue message arrives, a second process starts executing and trashes the first process (which has some static data structures).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, queue messages are processed in parallel. The default degree of parallelism is 16.

If you don't want parallel execution, you can set the `JobHostConfiguration.Queues.BatchSize` to `1`, as described [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/09/06/announcing-the-0-5-0-beta-preview-of-microsoft-azure-webjobs-sdk/).